# How to manage space effectively on a small SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, disk-space, disk-management

How do you manage disk space on a small SSD?

I bought a new PC that came with a 128GB SSD (local disk) and 1TB internal drive.

The OS takes up most of the space on the SSD.  From the moment I turned it on, I have installed every program into the larger internal drive, but the problem is that most programs that I need to use (Visual Studio, for example) install half of their crap on the local disk (the disk that the OS is on) Even if you specify a different drive to install it on. So now I only have 1GB space left and it doesn't look like there's anything I can do.

I can't repartition or format my drive because that will void my warranty. I don't usually give a damn about warranties, but this PC was expensive, and it's actually a replacement (brand new replacement) due to the previous (brand new) PC's DVD drive being faulty.

What can I do? Is there a way to force every program to install itself entirely in any location you specify, and nowhere else?

Comment: “I can't repartition or format my drive because that will void my warranty.” Why is that? That’s normal use!

Comment: @Daniel I'd like to answer that honestly, but the answer would turn into a full on rage fit.

Comment: I see. Better build a PC yourself next time. :D

Comment: @Daniel I had every intention to this time.  Ah well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way that just the OS should be taking up 128GB or close to it, even with Visual Studio. Granted VS does install a ton of stuff C (like it or not), but it shouldn't be close to the 100+ GB.

I'd recommend using [Wiztree](https://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wiztree-finds-the-files-and-folders-using-the-most-disk-space-on-your-hard-drive/) to determine what is taking up space on the drive. (it's freeware, and portable)

Some things you can do are:

relocate the paging file

disable Hibernation mode

relocate the Temp folder to the 1TB

relocate My Documents/My Pics/My videos

reduce the amount of space used by System Restore (or disable it)

I *do not* recommend relocating Program Files, Common Files, etc!

Comment: Windows 8.1 is taking up ~20 GB. I have Visual Studio 2015 RC installed, which takes up over 22GB. I specifically told it to install to D:\ but instead, it installed HALF (11GB) onto C:\. There are many other programs I need that don't even give you the option to choose where to install them! That's what's taking up the most space - the OS, Visual Studio, and the apps that give you no choice as to where they reside. I have already relocated the library folders (Music, Videos, Documents, Pictures) to the 1TB drive (it's actually 2TB but I forgot). I will try your other suggestions. Tha

Comment: ..thanks :). I just ran Disk Cleanup (didn't think I needed to since the PC is only a week old) and cleared a whole bunch of stuff. Apparently, much of the space was actually dedicated to (other than VS) previous windows updates files. Windows keeps previous updates even after you have installed more recent ones. There was an option to delete them so I did. I now have 24GB free space after doing that. Going to try your suggestions now and see how much more space I can get :)

Comment: Glad to help. Hibernation can free up as much as 5gb. Relocating the paging file can free up as much as 16gb depending on how much system ram you have. the temp folder can use a lot too.  -- btw, there IS a way to force many stubborn apps to install on another HDD, by using what are called Symlinks. but you have to be careful, you don't want to force the wrong things to relocate - some programs (like Google Chrome) have very complex install blueprints

Comment: just to give you an idea - I have my OS (win7-64) and many apps installed on my C drive (also an SSD), including photoshop and acrobat pro, and my entire C: drive is only using 30gb. - [here is a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ZMx86nF.jpg)

Comment: As an aside, @SE505: http://alternativeto.net/software/wiztree/ -- I've always loved http://windirstat.info/ (or in my case, a Mac alternative).

Comment: For some reason, even many new Microsoft software relies on itself being installed to the local disk, I don't know why they even have me the option to specify a different location.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to relocate your entire `Program Files` directory to the `D:` drive. There are several keys in `/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion`, depending on your OS version:

```
CommonFilesDir (REG_SZ) = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files"
CommonFilesDir (x86) (REG_SZ) = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files"
CommonW6432Dir (REG_SZ) = "C:\Program Files\Common Files"
ProgramFilesDir (REG_SZ) = "C:\Program Files (x86)"
ProgramFilesDir (x86) (REG_SZ) = "C:\Program Files (x86)"
ProgramFilesPath (REG_EXPAND_SZ) = "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
ProgramW6432Dir (REG_SZ) = "C:\Program Files"
```

Be aware that Microsoft [doesn't support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/933700) such modification and warns you that it may not be compatible with all your software.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I will give this some thought, but I was hoping that there would be a way that would be compatible with all software (wishful thinking, I know...). I don't really see any other alternative though. Would there be any issue with swapping the drives completely, like, reinstalling the OS on the big drive and just using the SSD as a small backup-like drive? Or does the OS _need_ to be on the SSD for any particular reason?

Comment: Well, the whole point of SSDs is to speed up the boot process and subsequent OS operation by having the most used system files on the fast SSD drive, so there *is* a reason.

Comment: For what I've heard, the Windows `system32` folder holds the 64 bit system files nowadays, and Windows automatically maps requests of 32 bit programs to the 32 bit files in some `SysWow64` folder. And all that was introduced as, apparently, too many (old?) programs are hardcoded to use the `system32` folder. That makes one wonder: how many programs still rely on `C:\Program Files`...

Comment: @Arjan too many.

Comment: Wait a minute. Could I just move the system32 folder to my big drive and create like a shortcut in its original location to the new location so when programs read from write to. It the files will be forwarded to the bigger drive?